# How can I combine csv files and add header rows with python?

Tags: python, csv

I have 50 `csv` files of price index data from St.Louis Fred, the format of each is like this:

[image]

And I want to combine multiple csv files and add one more row of header to them to achieve the following format:

[image]

So I can store the data in one csv file, may I know is there any way that I can do it with Python?

Comment: This can be done using the `csv` module in Python. Just Google for examples or read the docs for usage.

Comment: Alternatively, read each file using `pandas.read_csv()` and then concatenate or merge the dataframes into one dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repetition of the `DATE` column doesn't make sense. Unless there is some specific purpose. Also, while merging you want to be careful that the data on a particular line belongs to the same date.

Its better to use pandas if you are merging using **DATE** as the index and merge using **OUTER** method. So, the values from the same date are on the same lines.

```
import pandas as pd;

df1 = pd.read_table('file1.csv', sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_table('file2.csv', sep=',')
df3 = pd.read_table('file3.csv', sep=',')
```

So, basically load all the files you have as data frame. Then merge the files using `merge` or `reduce` function.

```
data_frames = [df1, df2, df3]
```

**you can add as many data-frames in the above code.**

Then merge them. To keep the values that belong to the same date you need to merge it on the `DATE`

```
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['DATE'],
                                            how='outer'), data_frames)
```

Then write the merged data to the csv file.

```
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df_merged, 'merged.txt', sep=',', na_rep='.', index=False)
```

This should give you

`DATE    VALUE1    VALUE2    VALUE3 ....`

Comment: got it, please check!

Answer (score 2):

This will vertically concatenate all the files in the provided directory (so you don't have to specify them in code). The files can have any number of columns and it can handle spaces in the values. However the files must all have the same number of rows.

It uses only modules csv and os.

```
import os
import csv

dir_base = r'H:\apps\xp\Desktop\localrepo\Temp'
dir_name = '-test2'
output_name = 'output.csv'

path = os.path.join(dir_base, dir_name)
out_path = os.path.join(dir_base, output_name)


def _extend(lines, lineno, line):
    try:
        lines[lineno].extend(line)
    except IndexError:
        lines.append(line)


def main():
    lines = []

    # read and generate new file
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as csvfile:
                f_in = csv.reader(csvfile)
                for lineno, line in enumerate(f_in, start=1):
                    if lineno == 1:
                        header = [''] * len(line)
                        header[0] = f
                        _extend(lines, 0, header)
                    _extend(lines, lineno, line)

    # print new file
    with open(out_path, 'w', newline='\n') as csvfile:
        csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

If your "csv" files have other delimiters (hence not technically "c"sv files), just change this part of the code `csv.reader(csvfile)` to indicate the delimiter, eg, `csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. How can we achieve the same output but vertically rather than horizontally ?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is great solution, but if you want a python std lib solution:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

csv_input_filenames = [
    'csvfile1.csv',
    'csvfile2.csv',
    'csvfile3.csv',
]
csv_output_filename = 'csv_out.csv'

# get the csv data
csv_files = [open(file_name) for file_name in csv_input_filenames]
csv_handles = [csv.reader(csv_file) for csv_file in csv_files]
rows = (list(chain(*row)) for row in zip(*csv_handles))

# write combined output
with open(csv_output_filename, 'wb') as csv_file:
    filenames_header = list(chain(
        *zip(csv_input_filenames, [''] * len(csv_input_filenames))))

    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(filenames_header)

    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)

# close input files
for csv_file in csv_files:
    csv_file.close()
```